# How to start learning socket programming using node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am interested to learn socket programming and to create a chat application using Node.js.

There are two different things exist 
   1) `net.Socket` class exposed by built-in `net` module 
   2) `socket.io` package. (Node.js implementation) 
 
Which one of them can be referred? 
If `socket.io` is a wrapper for `net.Socket`, why it's not imported by `socket.io`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with net.socket but if you are new to sockets in node, I would recommend socket.io. There are a lot more resources available and I would say it is a lot more commonly used.

Practicing by building a chat application is a good use case.

You can even follow socket.io's toturial [here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/)

Answer (score 0):

I just finished writing an app using socket.io, nodejs (express) and mongodb. For front end, I used ios 11.
I have to say that it is very easy to use these technologies given all the knowledge out there.

The basic socket.io flow works with duplex communication between front end (client) and backend (client). 
1. A client "emits" an event to server
2. Server acts upon it can can choose to emit an even back.
3. Server receives the event and acts on it..

For example:

In my ios app:

```
 func sendMessageToTheRoom(message: String, name: String, roomName: String) {
        socket.emit("messageToRoom", message, name, roomName)
    }
```

Then client responds like so:

```
    clientSocket.on('messageToRoom', function(message, name, roomName) {
        console.log(message);
        console.log(name);
        console.log(roomName);

        io.to(roomName).emit('messageReceived', message, name, roomName);

     });
```

And finally, the receiver clients act upon server's emit action like so:

```
socket.on("messageReceived") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in

        var messageDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()
        messageDictionary["message"] = dataArray[0] as! String as AnyObject
        messageDictionary["name"] = dataArray[1] as! String as AnyObject
        messageDictionary["roomName"] = dataArray[2] as! String as AnyObject

        print(messageDictionary["message"] as! String)

        if messageDictionary["name"] as? String != self.nickName {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let message = Message()
                message.text = messageDictionary["message"] as? String
                message.isSender = false
                self.messages?.append(message)
                self.chatCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notifications.newMessageSent.name, object: nil)

    }
```

But this is just an example.